# How to prevent onbeforeunload from running in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I had used `window.onbeforeunload = function()` when the user was trying to refresh the page by mistake and now I would like to cancel the loading of the page when he clicks on an icon?

Here is what I had tried, but it did not work.

```
crossremove.onclick = () => {

    /**
     * To prevent that the page does not refresh any more seen 
     * that one removed the file in the input. We have to do this.
     */
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
                        
    // REMOVE THE FILE IN THE FIELD INPUT
    inputFile.value = ""

    // HIDE THE ERROR OF THE FILE UPLOADED BY MISTAKE.
    fileUpload.style.display = 'none'

    // REMOVE THE TITLE OF THE IMAGE ERROR THAT WAS DISPLAYED 
    fileNameLabel.textContent = ''

    // RESHOW THE INPUT OF UPLOAD FILE.
    labelUplbl.style.display = null
                        
}
```

What could you suggest I do, please?

Comment: _"How to prevent onbeforeunload from running in pure javascript?"_ - You can't. There is no API in JS nor the DOM for blocking or removing registered event-listeners.

Comment: Oh no.  What could you suggest as an alternative, please?

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve...

Comment: Your previous solution seems just fine. If it worked, then keep it that way

Comment: Why do you assume that a page refresh is accidental and not deliberate? The act of refreshing exists on purpose, so I would always assume such actions to be deliberate.

Comment: @Dai When the user clicks on an element in the DOM, I would like the page to automatically cancel loading. Well, as you told me that the JS API blocks this. I would like to know do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @RichardsonOge By using `event.preventDefault()` and/or `stopPropagation()` in the first event-listener for that event - however if you're doing that it means you're likely doing something fundamentally wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what I had to do first.**

```
inputFile.addEventListener("change", function(){
                    /**
                     * Getting user select file and [0] this means if user 
                     * select multiple files then we'll select only the first one
                     */
                    file = this.files[0]
                    setInterval(function(){
                        var checkIfFileExist = file.name

                        if ( checkIfFileExist != '' ) {
                            window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                                return true
                            }
                        }
                    }, 1000)
                    dropArea.classList.add("active")
                    showFile() //calling function
                })
```

Comment: Your code will fail with a runtime error if `this.files.length === 0` which happens when a user de-selects a file. Also, your choice of a 1000ms wait is a bad idea: never assume the user will always use some minimum or arbitrary period of time to do something.